# Execute Ruby Cron

Tags: ruby, cron

I've reviewed several tutorials and other stackoverflow questions on the subject but have been unable to self administer a fix.

After several attempts to institute other solutions, here is my original code that I'm really hoping to get working:

```
00,30 10-20 * * * ruby  ~/Documents/GeneralAssembly/ForFun/SMS/sms.rb
```

By the way, the sms.rb is connected to Twillio. I'm setting up the Cron to text me every half hour and remind me not to snack in the middle of the day, :)

The file runs and works by itself, plus I receive mail when the cron attempts to run, but still not working together.

Please help as best you can. Let me know what I am misunderstanding. Thank you very much!

Comment: why not wrap that in a shell script with full paths and just call the shell script from cron.

Comment: see anything in the logs? by default you will see it in `/var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including the whole path to ruby

Comment: Worked instantly!!!! Thank you :)

I just needed to change ruby to /Users/iangoldfarb/.rbenv/shims/ruby

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use [the `whenever` gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever). It wraps cron jobs in a nice DSL and generates/updates your cron file for you. For example:

```
# config/schedule.rb

every 10.minutes do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
  rake "my:rake:task"
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end
```

Then test the output with `whenever -w` and apply it with `whenever --update-cronfile`

Comment: That is awesome! Thanks so much for sharing, I'll give this a trial today :)